# How to output Parentheses in UserMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a usermailer as follows:

```
mail( :from => "#{@user.full_name} \(Site.com\) <no-reply@site.com>",
      :to => @recipient_email,
      :subject => "Hello World"
)
```

I want this to output as:

```
from = "Full Name (Site.com) <no-reply@site.com>"
```

Problem is it is always:

```
from = "Full Name <no-reply@site.com>"
```

I tried escaping the parentheses but that did not work. Why can't I output the parentheses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to be the solution, but your From header appears to be badly formatted.

I think it should be

```
from = "\"Full Name (Site.com)\" <no-reply@site.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from = "Full Name (Site.com) <no-reply@site.com>"
```

I think this is also worked